# systate()/current_date() not working in HQL

Tags: hive, hql, hue

while doing this operation in HQl i am getting

java sql exception:error 10011 - invalid function sysdate(). getting same for current date too..

```
WHERE TO_DATE (CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) >= sysdate()-8
AND TO_DATE (CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day)) <= sysdate()-2
```

how i can rewrite it?
help me out of this

Answer (score 0):

as of hive 1.2.0 you can use `current_date()` , on previous versions it can be achieved with `>=date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),8)` f.i.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use unix_timestamp() / from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) (in your case) according to [hive manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) no matter which version of hive you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the Condition in where clause :

```
(((unix_timestamp(usage_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')) >= (unix_timestamp(date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') ,8),'yyyy-MM-dd'))) and ((unix_timestamp(usage_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')) >= (unix_timestamp(date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd') ,2),'yyyy-MM-dd'))))
```

Here usage_dt is you column name for date, and the DateFormat In Hive used as "yyyy-MM-dd" format so if you are havig any other format you can mention as here yyyyMMdd is the customr format of the sate.